# Postman - Test to Match Number of Objects in Nested Object

Tags: javascript, object, postman, postman-testcase

I want to write a test to validate the number of objects nested in "children" is equal to what I am expecting.  Let's say in this case it is 2.

This is the response body I am testing against:

```
{
    "result": {
        "line_item": {
            "name": null,
            "description": "abc",
            "quantity": 1.0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "sku": "xxx",
                    "quantity": 1.0,
                    "description": "abc"
                },
                {
                    "sku": "yyy",
                    "quantity": 3.0,
                    "description": "def"
                }
        ]
    }       
  }
}
```

I have tried a few things, one of them being this:

```
let josnData = pm.response.json();

var children = jsonData.result.line_item.chilren;

var length_children = children.length;

pm.test("Only 2 objects in Children", function (){
    pm.expect(length_children).to.eql(2);
});
```

This just throws an error.  Would appreciate any ideas how to tackle this. Very new to testing in postman and eager to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. But definitely interested in other ways.  Here is what I did.

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var list = body.result.line_item.children.length;

pm.test("Only 2 objects in children", function(){
    pm.expect(list).to.eql(2);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably would have done the same thing as your solution:

```
let children = pm.response.json().result.line_item.children;

pm.test("Only 2 objects in Children", function () {
    pm.expect(children.length).to.eql(2);
});
```